# How to increment the value of an object property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I increment "**week**" property?

```
def newweek
 current_user.userprofile.week += 1
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :action => "index"}
 end
end
```

The initial value is **0**. Each time **newweek** is run, the week should be incremented by **1**.

Unfortunately, each time **newwek** is run, the value remains to **1**. How do I fix that?

## EDIT

```
class NewWeekToUserprofile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_column :userprofiles, :week, :integer, :default => 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.increment` method.

```
current_user.userprofile.increment :week
```

Comment: Do I need to call save or something like that? Because nothing is happenning.

Comment: I've added "current_user.userprofile.save" and it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def newweek
 cu_p=current_user.userprofile
 cu_p.week=cu_p.week.nil? ? 1 : cu_p.week +1
 cu_p.save
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :action => "index"}
 end
end
```

Edited to test value of userprofile (nil or not)

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "useless use of + in void context"

Comment: I don't know because when I first created the userprofile class, week was not there. Then I added it using a migration. See the edit. When I update the other properties, everything works just fine. But when I try to update week, my application breaks.

Comment: From your updated post the default value is 0. What wording of the error your are getting?

Comment: This is what I'm getting: "useless use of + in void context"